# How to add collections to a data transfer class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have the following setup where a class contains a collection. When querying instances of this class I like to populate a data transfer class rather than the data class. However, Hibernate generates a wrong SQL query. What am I missing?

The Hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Thread" table="tbl_threads" schema="dbo">
    <id name="Id" type="integer">
        <column name="i_id"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <set name="keywords" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" optimistic-lock="false">
        <key>
            <column name="thread_id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Comment"/>
    </set>
<!-- ... -->
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="ThreadKeyword" table="tbl_keywords" schema="dbo">
    <composite-id name="id" 
        class="se.ericsson.eab.sdk.fido.server.api.pojos.report.ReportThreadKeywordId">
        <key-property name="keywordId" type="integer">
            <column name="keyword_id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="threadId" type="integer">
            <column name="thread_id" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
<!-- ... -->
</class>
```

The HQL I am using is

```
SELECT new Composite(t.id, t.keywords, ...) 
  FROM Thread t, ThreadKeyword tk 
  WHERE t.id = tk.id.threadId
```

This generates a SQL where the SELECT part contains only a dot for the keyword attribute:

```
select  thread1_.report_id as col_0_0_, . as col_92_0_ 
  from dbo.tbl_thread reportthre0_ inner join 
  dbo.tbl_keywords keywords4_ on reportthre0_.i_id=keywords4_.thread_id
```

It works fine when I query for the data class directly, i.e.

```
SELECT t 
  FROM Thread t, ThreadKeyword tk 
  WHERE t.id = tk.id.threadId
```

As I understand will Hibernate not find a column name for keywords in the thread table. That is right, since it is a collection. It rather needs to be populated using subsequent queries. If I omit the keywords in the constructor for the Composite class the query gets right but Hibernate won't populate the Set.

How do I get the keywords set populated?

Comment: The Composite class has no Hibernate mapping, since it used to work for plain properties without a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a collection.

**t.id** is a column/value

so Hibernate translates that into **thread1_.report_id as col_0_0_**. Hibernate even gave it the alias **col_0_0_**

**t.keywords** is a set of values so Hibernate just can't translate the collection into a column/value.

> A query includes a list of columns to be included in the final result
>   immediately following the SELECT keyword - Wikipedia

Now the

```
SELECT t  FROM Thread t, ThreadKeyword tk  WHERE t.id = tk.id.threadId
```

works fine because Hibernate knows how to translate the query you have there into SQL.

Comment: Hi, ok the I guessed right. But given the restrictions that I need to use the `Composite` class, is there a way to fetch the keywords into this class?

Comment: The thing is that the ThreadKeyword is still an Entity Class which contradicts with your statement about Data Transfer objects. If want to map Entities to DTOs you could use Dozer which is an Object to Object mapper. You would use the HQL that works and then Dozer to map the resulting object to your DTO.

Comment: I would avoid DTOs even if they have some advantages. It slows down development for a start and if you are going to use a mapper it slows down your application too.

Comment: Can't afford to slow things down. Since the keywords are basically strings they will be held as a concatenated string in the same table as Report. This creates redundance but doesn't affect performance, at least on reading.

Comment: If this is an isolated case you could map the Entity objects into your DTO objects using code. It might look dirty but it would be the fastest solution, if using DTOs is really important for your project.